# How to right align and pad number with max width using format specification mini language

Tags: python, numpy, string-formatting

I need to be able to do this in a way that I can pass the format specification to the `fmt` parameter in numpy.savetxt(). I want to:

1. Take a float
2. Pad with zeros
3. Right align the number
4. Truncate to 8 digits with 3 decimal places (including negative signs)

I tried this:

`'{:0>8}'.format('%.3f')`

which I am passing to the numpy.savetxt() function but it is not able to truncate the values to the specified width of 8 digits.

for example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.random(10,10)*10
np.savetxt("testfile.txt", arr, fmt='{:0>8}'.format('%.3f')), delimiter='')
```

gives the output:

```
0000-11.54900006.870000021.8620000-0.3420000-20.55700005.5390000-2.343000012.1160000-8.949000012.097
00002.1510000-8.29800004.4310000-6.1050000-4.2280000-11.462000019.7120000-10.29800006.848000013.074
0000-0.536000010.8160000-10.329000011.328000017.5580000-2.83200007.795000012.10400001.834000011.550
0000-2.6060000-10.25000008.5310000-6.839000010.7350000-15.7570000-0.274000011.17500000.9940000-7.971
000022.6050000-1.4860000-2.37000000.806000010.3560000-8.86100002.430000018.6110000-3.1820000-5.281
000022.0720000-7.299000018.0320000-2.556000010.4690000-1.21900006.23900006.3840000-8.1560000-10.781
0000-2.0590000-4.8680000-22.31700005.0220000-9.5820000-2.873000021.6050000-0.9110000-9.7050000-4.920
0000-8.4410000-4.061000023.6880000-2.7050000-0.5700000-3.4070000-10.48900005.1820000-2.32500000.581
000016.9450000-19.11100002.955000018.28900000.62500003.34200003.1910000-14.7660000-4.93600002.139
000016.1390000-1.58100002.095000032.02800006.63900002.07300006.3080000-12.91900001.42500001.447
```

So obviously the values are not being truncated properly as each line should be the same length and each column should be fixed width essentially.

How can I modify that format specifier being passed to the `fmt` parameter of numpy's savetxt function to get the desired result?

Comment: I don't think `'{:0>8}'.format('%.3f')` does what you think it does.  The `format` function is called immediately and you end up passing the string `'0000%.3f'` to `savetxt`, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Does using `fmt='%09.3f'` gives you the result you want?

Comment: Yup! I just tried something similar as you posted but your answer gives the right number of digits as well. If you post an answer and explain I think it will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `'{:0>8}'.format('%.3f')` is evaluated immediately before `savetxt` ever gets a chance to even look at it.  This means what `savetxt` sees from *its perspective* is simply the string `'0000%.3f'`, which doesn't do what you want.

After looking at the [various](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) on the format specification, I think using `fmt='%09.3f'` should give you the results that you want.  To dissect this:

- The `0` means it's zero-padded.
- The `9` means there are 9 characters (since `.` requires an extra character).
- The `.3` means there are 3 decimal places.
- Lastly, the `f` specifies decimal notation (as opposed to scientific or other kinds of notation).

Floating-point numbers are padded to the right by default so there's no need to worry about that.